# How can i do this I want to store Views in mysql db in 1000=1k, 100000=100k, 1000000=1M and so on

Tags: php, mysql

I have php code below i want to do this I want to store Views in mysql db in 1000=1k, 100000=100k, 1000000=1M and so on so can any one please tell me how can i do this

```
function updateVideoView()
{
    require_once("config.php");
    $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
    $event_json = json_decode($input,true);
    //print_r($event_json);

    if(isset($event_json['id']))
    {
        $id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($event_json['id'] , ENT_QUOTES));
           
        mysqli_query($conn,"update videos SET view =view+1 WHERE id ='".$id."' ");

        $array_out[] = 
            array(
            "response" =>"success");
            
        $output=array( "code" => "200", "msg" => $array_out);
        print_r(json_encode($output, true));
        
    }
    else
    {
        $array_out = array();
                
        $array_out[] = 
            array(
            "response" =>"Json Parem are missing");
        
        $output=array( "code" => "201", "msg" => $array_out);
        print_r(json_encode($output, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` and `strip_tags` when storing data in the DB. Use them when displaying data on web pages.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would you want to store anything other than plain numbers in the database? You should store it as ordinary numbers, then you can abbreviate it when you're displaying it.

Comment: As already mentioned, storing the number abbreviated probably isn't what you want.  If you store 1M, how do you increment it?  Or how would 1K become 2K without being 1.001K etc.